# How do you reset the HTML cache in macOS Mail?

Tags: macos, email, caching, html-email, macos-mail-app

I'm developing an app that sends HTML mail.  I just condensed all of my CSS code into a .css file that is now linked in the mail header:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://example.com/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="email-body">

...etc...
```

I discovered a mistake in the .css file, re-uploaded it to example.com, and now for the life of me I can't get Mail to use it properly.  Mail must still have the old .css file cached.

I know with Safari I can clear the cache with the `Safari -> Clear History` menu item.  How do I do this in Mail?

Comment: I can of course rename the .css file so Mail will pull that in, but it'd be better to know how to clear the cache.

Comment: Just an fyi, not all email clients read linked CSS or CSS in the head. Might be easier to use a CSS inliner.

Comment: Oh wow, good to know.  I'll do that then.